# jQuery custom validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate a login form. It iss working fine when I validate just mobile numbers. If I validate both mobile and password, then only the last one is working – rest is not working well. Can anybody help me, what is wrong in this code?

What I tried:

```js
function loginValidation() {
  if ($('[name="mobileNo"]').val() == '') {
    $('.validation_error').text('Mobile number is reuired').addClass('validation_active');
  } else {
    $('.validation_error').text('').removeClass('validation_active');
  }

  if ($('[name="loginPassword"]').val() == '') {
    $('.validation_error').text('Password is reuired').addClass('validation_active');
  } else {
    $('.validation_error').text('').removeClass('validation_active');
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.validation_error').text('').removeClass('validation_active');
  }, 3000);

};
```

```css
.validation_error {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #ee2e24;
  z-index: 10000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 39px #333;
  transition: all 0.45s;
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

.validation_active {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="loginBox">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" name="mobileNo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="loginPassword">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" onclick="loginVelidation();">Login</button>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="validation_error"></div>
```

Now is `password is reuired` is display when i click on login button. But first i want to validate `mobile is reuired`

Comment: Your appending to .validation_error 2 times for the conditions. So, it will overwrite the first one, while password condition satisfied. Change your If conditions according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like below :

```
    function loginVelidation() 
   {
      if ($('[name="mobileNo"]').val() == '') {
            $('.validation_error').text('Mobile number is reuired').addClass('validation_active');
      } 
    else if ($('[name="loginPassword"]').val() == '') {
             $('.validation_error').text('Password is reuired').addClass('validation_active');
    else {
        $('.validation_error').text('').removeClass('validation_active');
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.validation_error').text('').removeClass('validation_active');
      }, 3000);

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but you are overriding the error message  $('.validation_error') if you want to show both errors then you to create separate error holder element.